# VueJS datalist in conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I have an `<input list="data-list" ...>` field with some `<datalist id="data-list">`, and all is wrapped within conditional rendering such as `v-if="showInput"` or `v-bind:class={show : showInput}`, then I get an error and nothing works. Just removing the conditional rendering makes stuff work, that is:

```html
<!-- works! -->
<div>
<input list="choices" id="choice" name="choice" placeholder="(select category)" />
<datalist id="choices">
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- does *not* work -->
<div v-if="showChoices">
<input list="choices" id="choice" name="choice" placeholder="(select category)" />
<datalist id="choices">
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

In the vue component there is

```js
 ...
 data : function() { 
   return {
    showChoices : true
   } 
 }
 ...
```

The error (Firefox webconsole) is:

> [Vue warn]: Failed setting prop "list" on : value choices is invalid. TypeError: "setting getter-only property "list""

Is it somehow possible to use the datalist feature in a conditionally shown element?

**EDIT** To be clear, there might be another root cause for this issue, but it happens in my case as described above.

I have seen [this](https://gist.github.com/lucasjellema/1c92c052d3a278ee27d17cfa3ea3b54a) and [this](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2018/04/12/datalists-with-vuejs) examples, which somehow don't work in my setup.

Comment: `list="choices"` is referencing a dom element that doesn't exist. you can't hide the datalist   and bind the list property to the datalist as well

Comment: Same argument seems to apply to the two examples (I just added the links) - they somehow seem to work though, but not on my machine

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about `<datalist>`. This example (with a `v-if`) seems to work for me in Chrome and Firefox, though... https://jsfiddle.net/3mh2rzns/

Comment: Thanks, it appears that this has something to do with my setup, not with `v-if`. I tried a bit and it seems that as soon as vue touches my datalist, something breaks. I'll have to figure this out in the larger overall context, it seems

Comment: Apparently this problem was related to vue3-beta, which I used in the project. Moving the source back to vue2 resolved the issue.